# Angular JS custom service success callback not working

Tags: angularjs

Trying out a basic example of Angular JS.

Created a `index.html` file and including the `main.html` file - controller `MainController` and using the service - `service1`.

The data grid population is written in the success callback `(onCallComplete)` of the `service1`, which is not called for some reason.

Neither its showing any error.

Where am I going wrong?

[Link to my code](http://plnkr.co/edit/VMUO7apzLnHhDs27zfDo?p=preview)

Comment: The code, the expected behavior and the actual behavior must be in the question itself. Not just in a plunkr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your `onCallComplete` from

```
var onCallComplete = function(data) {
          $scope.user = data;
          service1.getRepos($scope.user).then(onReposComplete, onError);
        };
```

to

```
function onCallComplete(data) {
          console.log(data);
          $scope.user = data;
          service1.getRepos($scope.user).then(onReposComplete, onError);
        }
```

Here is the working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XECmuxa0SF3i0t3DdGE8?p=preview)

or move your `service1.getUser($scope.username).then(onCallComplete,onError);` beneath `onCallComplete` like given below.

```
  var onCallComplete = function(data) {
          $scope.user = data;
          service1.getRepos($scope.user).then(onReposComplete, onError);
        };
    service1.getUser($scope.username).then(onCallComplete,onError);
```

The Reason is When you define your function as var `onCallComplete =function(data)` the function definition happens at **runtime**. but using `function onCallComplete(data)` the function gets defined while **parsing** the script.So it would be available at any point during runtime.